# What kind of protection does a circuit need to have for reading the output of a CT?

Tags: pcb-design, protection, circuit-protection, instrumentation

A CT (current transformer) is installed to measure the line current for digital measurement and protection devices. In many cases, the CT is installed in open weather or on poles, making it vulnerable to lightning.

The voltage across the burden resistor of the CT is amplified and measured through a microcontroller to decide what to do. But this simple circuit doesn't have any protection. If somehow the insulation fails or there is lightning, there is a high possibility that the circuit will be damaged.

What kind of protection needs to be used on the PCB to increase safety? **The maximum CT current in normal condition for my application will be 100 mA. Primary voltage is 220 V RMS AC distribution line.**

Comment: What CT do you mean? Computer Tomography unit? (Probably not.)
**Edit**: Thanks!

Comment: no, it's Current transformer

Comment: What insulation failing are you concerned about? What current transformer? Measuring the current of what? 22kV three phase? Or 120VAC single phase? What safety are you concerned about? Electrical safety? Or do you mean protection for the electronics?

Comment: @Kartman edited the question. The voltage is 220 volts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *the CT is installed in open weather or on poles, making it vulnerable
> to lightning.*

Nothing is going to save the CT from a **direct** lightning strike.

> *What kind of protection needs to be used in the PCB to increase
> safety?*

**Define the threat numerically**

There are worldwide standards that can be used for estimating the effects of **indirect** lightning strikes (namely EN61000-4-5) but, they won't necessarily cover a **direct** strike. **Direct** lightning strikes create a bit of a wasteland so, maybe they are a little beyond the scope of most requirements. Hence...

- Define the threat voltage,
- Define the threat source impedance and
- Define the threat waveform profile

That's how engineers do it AND, EN61000-4-5 is actually quite helpful. In fact, it's so helpful that I designed a fairly beefy TVS in a simulator and it passed the real test without smoke or tears or bed-wetting.

It becomes a fairly simple theoretical exercise to design protection once it's defined. Of course it'll need testing but, there's no point blindly guessing what might be needed and then failing some moderately expensive surge testing at a test house. Do the right thing first and give yourself the best chance of success.

**Define the victim**

But of course you also need to define at what level a current or voltage surge might start to create problems for your victim circuit. I can't tell you what that is; you need to define that and then, a proper analysis can be done.

Answer (score 1):

A CT can burn if the burden resistor fails open circuit .Clamp diodes or Zeners will save the CT if the burden is open circuit.This can protect your fragile input pin .Some simple RC filtering after the burden further protects against transients .